# Updating remote database table from local database table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update remote database from local database, I have written php script to do that but it is showing me fatal error.

Remote database and local database has same name, same table, same fields.

I have tried this way but its not working.

```
    $tablename="pc_games";
    $database = 'games';

    $local_query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename LIMIT 100 OFFSET $remoterows";
    $local_result = mysql_query($local_query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

    while($list=mysql_fetch_array($local_result))
    {
    $remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SETLECT * from $tablename");
    $remote_update_result = mysql_query($remote_update, $remote_connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
```

Please see and suggest any possible approach to do this.

Comment: Can you show us the error? Also, are you sure the remote connections are defined properly?

Comment: Fatal error: SQL, thats it. yes connection are proper, no problem there.

Comment: Try this for your error handler: ` or die (mysql_error());`, then tell us the result.

Comment: Change `trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);` to `die( mysql_error() );`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SETLECT * from pc_games' at line 1

Comment: Wherever did you get the idea to do things this way? Taking the result of one query and passing it right back in is...unusual.

Comment: @TallboY I found another error, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO $tablename SETLECT * from $tablename"
```

This is an invalid SQL statement. SETLECT have to be SELECT

Comment: my bad i typed it wrong, it is now showing `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: You have a unique constraint and you are trying to insert the same record more than once which violates the unique constraint. Either remove the existing row or insert a new one with different value for primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Your remote query has a syntax error: `"INSERT INTO $tablename SETLECT * from $tablename"`. You mean `SELECT` instead of `SETLECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement code:

```
$tablename="pc_games";
$database = 'games';

$local_query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename LIMIT 100 OFFSET $remoterows";
$local_result = mysql_query($local_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while($list=mysql_fetch_array($local_result))
{
$remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SELECT * from $tablename");
$remote_update_result = mysql_query($remote_update, $remote_connection) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

What you did wrong, was you mistyped this line:

```
$remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SETLECT * from $tablename");
```

Notice that you used `SETLECT`, instead of what you meant to use (perhaps): `SELECT`.

I also marvel at how long it takes to detect a typing error.

I changed all your error handlers to the ones I mentioned in the comments. Use them in the future. They're better.

**UPDATE:** What did you do with your code? I just realised something drastic:

```
$remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SELECT * from $tablename");
$remote_update_result = mysql_query($remote_update, $remote_connection) or die (mysql_error());
```

First of all, you're running `mysql_query` on a result. Second, you aren't inserting anything `INSERT INTO $tablename`. Is it my fault, or are you doing something dreadfully wrong?

Comment: yes you are right, there is no error showing now, and nothing gets inserted in remote database, what should i do.

Comment: @TallboY so what did you change your insert code to? May I take a look?

Comment: I have asked another question, please see it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445909/insert-new-rows-from-local-table-to-remote-table

Answer (score 0):

1. Why are you looping through the results(with `while($list=mysql_fetch_array($local_result))`
   ) when you absolutely don't need it?
2. Why have you set the error function everywhere as: `trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);`.
3. Why are you still using `mysql_*` method for databases?
4. If you just need to insert data from another table, just put:

---

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SELECT * FROM $tablename LIMIT 100 OFFSET $remoterows") or die(mysql_error());
```

and be done with it.

Comment: I want to update remote database from local database when new rows are added, sorry i didn't mentioned that.

Comment: it shows `Duplicate entry '34' for key 'PRIMARY'` with this method, i have only 33 rows in remote database and i just inserted a new row in my local database, then why this error

Comment: Can't say for sure. Is your `$remoterows` set to 33?