# Insert new rows from local table to remote table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert new rows from local table to remote table, i have made a php script for it but it is not working.

Remote and local - database, table and fields are same.

I am doing this way

```
//connection
$remote_hostname='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306';
$hostname='localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$remote_connection = mysql_connect($remote_hostname, $username, $password); 
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 

$tablename="pc_games";
$database = 'games';

// some row count here $remoterows

$local_query = "SELECT * FROM $tablename LIMIT 100 OFFSET $remoterows";
$local_result = mysql_query($local_query, $connection) or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 

while($list=mysql_fetch_array($local_result))
{
$remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SELECT * from $tablename");
$remote_update_result = mysql_query($remote_update, $remote_connection) or trigger_error(mysql_error());    
}
```

This is not working and showing error `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`, but there is no duplicate entry.

If i do it this way it works, new rows get inserted into remote database.

```
while($list=mysql_fetch_array($local_result))
{
$id=$list['id'];    
$pflink=$list['pflink'];    
$image=$list['image'];  
$pagelink=$list['pagelink'];    
$title=$list['title'];
    // and so on... 

$remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SET id='$id', image='$image', pagelink='$pagelink', title='$title'......");
$remote_update_result = mysql_query($remote_update, $remote_connection) or trigger_error(mysql_error());    
}
```

I have a many colums in database and also many database, i want to do it the first way, as i want to re use these codes for another database with just changing `$database` and `$tablename`
in require file for another database.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Comment: and you did not forget to change $tablename variable? And you can always skip double selects and INSERT data into another table via "INSERT INTO tablename (AS) SELECT ..."

Comment: ah, you want to use the same tablename on different databases. Can you show me where you create $remote_connection and $connection?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: ya, i will convert to mysqli once my coding is finished.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot span a local and remote query in one request:

```
$remote_update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename SELECT * from $tablename");
```

This is supposed to get data from the **local select** and **insert** it into the **remote database**?

The query operates on 1 database, and 1 database only. You are trying to fetch data from a table and insert it on the same table. And of course, this gives a `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: yes, this query is acting on local database only, can you tell me any way around.

Comment: You answered your own question. There is no other way then fetching from local and inserting into remote. Or .. setup replication between the databases.

Answer (score 0):

despite the question is so old, you can check "CLONE" supported from MYSQL 8.0.17: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/clone-plugin-remote.html

This allow copy from localDB to remoteDB so easy.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32935251)

Comment: thanks master @Daraan by your lesson :-)